# Setting response header with javascript

Tags: javascript, response-headers

I'm having troubles with collecting json values from a URL in my application. When I try to get them a error log is displayed in the console saying that origin is not allowed by access-control-allow-origin.

I researched a bit and found out that response headers have to be set to Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

How can I do that using pure javascript? No jquery or any other library.

This is my current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var xmlHttp = null;
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", "http://example.com/id=69", false );
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    console.log("JSON values from URL: ");
    console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I researched a bit and found out that response headers have to be set to Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
>
> How can I do that using pure javascript? No jquery or any other library.

You can't, not unless your **server** is running JavaScript (NodeJS, etc.).

The *server* has to allow access to the resource from the origin of your document. The way it works is:

- The browser asks permission to access the resource (this is called a "preflight" request), telling the server what resource it wants access to, etc.
- The server replies with the appropriate headers telling the browser whether access will be allowed.
- The browser sends the actual request.
- The server responds to it (again including the relevant headers).

I believe there are situations where the pre-flight isn't necessary. All of that is handled for you by the `XMLHttpRequest` object.

Details in [the Cross-Origin Resource Sharing specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/).

Comment: My server is running NodeJS. Can I set the response headers then?

Comment: @MarkoĆilimković: Of course, in code on the server using [`response.setHeader`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value). CORS is pretty finicky, you need to be sure you're allowing everything the client is asking for, which means examining the request headers the browser sent.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder this browser extension resolves CORS policy issue on client side . how it can be done without extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en-US

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i mean the extension is also using the javascript on client-side but still able to override the CORS issues. So, why it can't be done using javaScript in html page.

Comment: @SatinderBajwa - Because extensions can do things web-page code can't.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this on client side, your server must send these headers.