# embedding another html content div to my current html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]

I have 2 separate HTML pages. What I'm trying to do is to pull a div from the second HTML page to look like the image on the right. When I click on todays news it should display below and not like a hyperlink.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('href link of current').click(function() {
    $("div of another html").load('today.html h2 h3');
  });
});
});
```

Comment: I assume this isn't working? If so check the URL is correct, and that there's no errors in the console. I'd also advise against including content in pages using AJAX. Doing it server side is better for a long list of reasons.

Comment: I think you are looking for iframe, https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp  or answerr above is make sense

Comment: The error may be occuring due to CORB. Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50873764/cross-origin-read-blocking-corb

Comment: Do you get any warnings or errors in the console?

Comment: @UllasHunka it won't be a CORB problem as the OP is making a request to the local domain

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Then there is only one error which can occur i.e. wrong URL

Comment: That's my guess too

Comment: What selector is `href link of current`? Also do you really have `h3` inside `h2` in today.html?