# GETting JSON data cross-site using JavaScript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, get

I am trying to GET some JSON data from [the following url](https://brf.nutrislice.com/menu/api/digest/school/black-river-falls-high-school/menu-type/lunch/date/2018/10/16/). I am having trouble making this work.

You see, I am trying to integrate the school's lunch menu through NutriSlice. We are using a digital signage system called RiseVision, and they have an HTML widget. This, of course, means I can only use HTML and JavaScript - makes things more difficult for me.

My code is as follows:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div>test</div>

    <script>

    $.ajax({type: "get",
            url: "https://brf.nutrislice.com/menu/api/digest/school/black-river-falls-high-school/menu-type/lunch/date/2018/10/16/",
            data: {method: "getQuote",format: "json",lang: "en"},
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonp: "jsonp",
            jsonpCallback: "myJsonMethod"
    }); 

    function myJsonMethod(response){
  $("div").append(" " + response);
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Nothing ever works for this. Nothing gets returned. Why? I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. The link I attached above shows the Django page for the API I'm looking at here.

Your help is very much appreciated! :)

EDIT:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( response );
    $("div").append(" " + obj.menu_items[0]);
```

Further clarification: Here is an example JSON from the data I need.

```
{"date":"2018-10-16","menu_items":["Taco Meat","Shredded Cheddar","Tortilla Chips","Tortilla Shell"],"images":["https://client-food-images.nutrislice.com/images/WD/WDeTEDdT2YDit97pdpUq7T/1474319790_787275__taco.jpg.1024x0_q85.jpg","https://client-food-images.nutrislice.com/images/eR/eRQamewxbJbFdAAbkUa5UK/1472157292_144997__ShrededCheddarCheese-IGH.jpg.1024x0_q85.jpg","https://client-food-images.nutrislice.com/images/4N/4NrHbqSdtFSa9HjQTM4WwT/1472157795_18851__tortillachips-m.jpg.1024x0_q85.jpg","https://client-food-images.nutrislice.com/images/wx/wx7bT4QGjLD8wNuK9oMtki/1473879858_737966__tortilla.jpg.1024x0_q85.jpg"],"holiday_text":null}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "https://brf.nutrislice.com/menu/api/digest/school/black-river-falls-high-school/menu-type/lunch/date/2018/10/16/",
    data: {
        method: "getQuote",
        format: "json",
        lang: "en"
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response); // check the console
        $(".s").append(" " + response)// this will not work properly
    }
});
```

keep in mind that you are trying to add a json object to an html document, that is not going to show well, you would have to take those data and use them in such a way that they are displayed correctly in the div

Comment: Alright, so why won't something like this work? (See edit in post)

Comment: The response in the callback success is already a json, you dont need to parse it. Try with $("div").append(" " + response.menu_items);

Comment: That doesn't work. It's confusing me heavily lol. I put the JSON in question in the post as an edit.

Comment: The API you are calling have not allowed the cross-domain calls. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50873764/cross-origin-read-blocking-corb

Comment: The docs say this: HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

Comment: check this out i can do it from mi local, and i can saw the output https://imgur.com/a/eZfNrsh

Answer (score 0):

Check the console (right click on page then inspect element). You will probably see something like this:

[image: CORB message]

Seems you are running into a protection specifically designed to prevent what you are trying to do, which is to send, from an unknown location, a request for the page's data. I am not an expert on CORB but hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Comment: It is definitely meant to be accessed though :/ I do see some header info in this link....https://brf.nutrislice.com/menu/api/digest/school/black-river-falls-high-school/menu-type/lunch/date/2018/10/16/?format=api

Comment: I would guess it is your browser. Look up how to disable CORB in whatever browser you use and see if that works? Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome) will help

Answer (score 0):

1. change `dataType: "jsonp",` to `dataType: "json",`. It's json, not jsonp
2. remove the line `jsonp: "jsonp",` or change to `jsonp: false,`
3. change `jsonpCallback: "myJsonMethod"` to `success: myJsonMethod`. make sure remove double quotes around myJsonMethod.
4. in your myJsonMethod function, change `$("div").append(" " + response);` to `$("div").append(" " + response.menu_items[0]);`

You will see 'test Taco Meat' on your screen.