# Django Development Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) (not CORS)

Tags: ajax, django, localhost, cross-origin-read-blocking

I am trying to test a call to my local Django development server. This is an AJAX call that returns a JSON object. The Django view does this:

```
return JsonResponse(response, safe=False)
```

I test this by launching the Django server (which runs the back end) and then launching my browser and opening the HTML page I have modified. These pages are not served by Django.

In Firefox, I can make the ajax call on the page. It returns the correct data, with the correct MIME type.

In Chrome, I can not. I get the following error:

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response http://localhost:8000/dataload/alljson with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
```

I have tried to search for the solution to this problem. I've checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50873764/cross-origin-read-blocking-corb), but the suggestion to clear my cache doesn't do anything. I've also found suggestions that involve using `django-cors-headers`, but this is CORB (not CORS). Nonetheless, I've installed `corsheaders` and set `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True` to eliminate that as a possibility.

My `MIDDLEWARE` setting has this

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
...
"corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
"django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
...
]
```

The response headers I get in Firefox are:

```
Content-Length      12827
Content-Type        application/json
Date        Wed, 06 Feb 2019 18:38:03 GMT
Server      WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.6.7
Vary        Origin
X-Frame-Options     SAMEORIGIN
```

I am calling `http://localhost:8000/dataload/alljson`. If I call `http://localhost:8000/dataload/alljson/` (with the trailing slash), I get a 404.

Still no dice.

How can I get Chrome to allow the response from my development Django server for this ajax call?

Comment: Is `'corsheaders'` in `INSTALLED_APPS` and `'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware'` at the top of `MIDDLEWARE`? Did you check the headers sent by the server in Firefox where the request succeeds? What headers are there? Are you sending the request to a URL that ends in a slash? A missing slash may cause this too.

Comment: Yes it is installed

Comment: First comment got truncated, sorry. Continuing: Is `'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware'` at the top of `MIDDLEWARE`? Did you check the headers sent by the server in Firefox where the request succeeds? What headers are there? Are you sending the request to a URL that ends in a slash? A missing slash may cause this too.

Comment: @EndreBoth I've updated my question with answers to your questions.

Comment: Well, there are clearly no CORS headers in the server response :(. Do you use any other custom middleware?

Comment: But why does Chrome even treat the request as cross-origin if it goes to the same address as the one the page was served from?

Comment: According to some reports, Chrome has a bug in implementing CORS on localhost: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67743 – I've never run into it though, Chrome seems to be accessing my local server just fine.

Comment: I am having the same problem with the newer Chrome versions. Used to work fine before.