# Warning in Chrome about Cross-Origin Read Blocking

Tags: javascript, java, html, google-chrome, browser

It is Spring and VueJs application
I am learning how to use OAuth google(sorry for bad explain), in application.properites i am adding my 'security.oauth2.client.clientId' and 'security.oauth2.client.clientSecret'

No problems with compilation and no exceptions. I starting localhost:9000 as written in my properties, and its 404 Error with warning in console: 
**Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response {here link of google.account... + with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details }**

To check if its working, I open localhost:9000/country and its shows my json formatted data as it have to be.
So i think its problem not about my code excatly, but I am not sure.

After I checked my index.html - there was no "http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;". I was sure its about that. But no... It still shows that Warning.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/js/**", "/error**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public PrincipalExtractor principalExtractor(UserDetailsRepo userDetailsRepo) {
        return map -> {
            String id = (String) map.get("sub");

            User user = userDetailsRepo.findById(id).orElseGet(() -> {
                User newUser = new User();
                newUser.setId(id);
                newUser.setName((String) map.get("name"));
                newUser.setEmail((String) map.get("email"));
                newUser.setGender((String) map.get("gender"));
                newUser.setLocale((String) map.get("locale"));
                newUser.setUserpic((String) map.get("picture"));

                return newUser;
            });

            user.setLastVisit(LocalDateTime.now());

            return userDetailsRepo.save(user);
        };
    }
}
```

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MainController {

    @GetMapping
    public String main(Model model, @AuthenticationPrincipal User user){
        HashMap<Object, Object> data = new HashMap<>();

        data.put("profile", user);
        data.put("messages", null);

        model.addAttribute("frontendData", data);

        return "index";
    }
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "usr")
@Data
public class User {
    @Id
//    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String userpic;
    private String email;
    private String gender;
    private String locale;
    private LocalDateTime lastVisit;
}
```

Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://accounts.google.{etc} with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50873764/cross-origin-read-blocking-corb)

Comment: Have you checked if your server app has cors enabled? If not, you need to make your cors policy accepts any domain(not safe) or localhost:9000 (on ur dev configs)

Comment: could explain please?) you mean application.properties?
security.oauth2.client.clientId=
security.oauth2.client.clientSecret=
security.oauth2.client.accessTokenUri=
security.oauth2.client.userAuthorizationUri=
security.oauth2.client.clientAuthenticationScheme=
security.oauth2.resource.userInfoUri=
security.oauth2.resource.preferTokenInfo=

server.port=9000
all that i have