# Ajax status is 200 but error event triggers instead of success

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, error-handling, undefined

Today I am facing a strange issue that I never faced before. My ajax call is returning response with 200 status but somehow it always trigger error event instead of success. This is what I am doing

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "swap.php",
        data: "key=dbdcd39f0f8f5077e7308f3d3d5d8cac&code="+$("#code").val(),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType:"json",
        beforeSend: function() {
                $("#msg").html("<img src='imgs/loading_circle.gif'/>");
        },
        success: function(result){
                alert(result);
        },
        error: function(xhr,status,error){
            alert(error.Message); // receiving Undefined message
        }
    });
```

PHP code of swap.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$resp["data"]="Record updated successfully";
print json_encode($resp);
?>
```

This is the response which I get when directly put the url in address bar

[image]

Below is the screenshot of chrome's network tab

[image]

Comment: are you sending your response using json_encode ?

Comment: No but response status is 200 and I am doing some database stuff which is also getting update successfully as per the parameters supplied.

Comment: In jQuery .ajax(), if the dataType: 'json' setting is specified, server must return a valid JSON formatted String, else error is thrown.

Comment: So, you mean this is not a valid json? {"data":"Record updated successfully"}

Comment: yes try this way around echo json_encode($resp);die;

Comment: No error getting the same response {"data":"Record updated successfully"}

Comment: means still going to error handler ?

Comment: Yes that is the issue. I have done this many times before but never faced such issue. Even in same project I have many ajax calls requesting same server and all of them working fine. So corsserver is also not an issue here.

Comment: this might be cross domain error as in your code I can see it is sending request as Options instead of get

Comment: Resolved the issue by removing content and datatype from request headers. Corssorigin was not an issue because I have lot of ajax requests in same project requesting same server and haven't faced this issue before. But this is the first time I am doing GET operation with query string parameters. I always used form values before.

Comment: Okay that’s sounds great. Can you make an upvote to my answer for my efforts

Answer (score 2):

The response image you're showing not the actual request, it's a pre flight check, Check the Request method it's `OPTIONS` not the `"GET"` as what you are trying. it's just checking for the `"CORS"` in this request. Not the actual ajax call.

Check the actual request, just after this. You will find the error.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to do that? I mean checking the request.

Comment: And how it is getting response headers correctly if the case is what you are saying? If I change header type in serverside php the same thing reflects in chrome network tab.

Comment: In the headers of this request, you see "Request Method: OPTIONS". That means the ajax is just verifying that if it can access the resource, just by some hand shake technique but not calling the actual request. so there will be 2 ajax calls. filter your request and check all the "XHR" request. you will find the 2 request in there.

Comment: Yes another one is also there with these stuffs : OPTIONS /45sde7r85d4s7e8r/swap.php?key=dbdcd39f0f8f5077e7308f3d3d5d8cac&code=3&_=1577339801702 HTTP/1.1
Host: xyz.com
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9

Comment: and what you see in response for the another request, also what's the status?

Comment: Ajax call is doing its work perfectly fine. I mean I am supplying some values to server and based on supplied values the DB is also getting update successfully. I don't know how to check the response here because every time it triggers error and in error.Message I am only getting Undefined message.

Comment: console.log(xhr), the first parameter of error function and see what's happening there.

Comment: It says. Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin

Comment: That's it.. that's what the error is and that's why the error function is triggering. Now you need to resolve this, You can take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50873764/cross-origin-read-blocking-corb

Comment: since my goal is achieved. Could you please tell me any way to get this message from xhr, so that I can check for this CORB error, ignore it and proceed with further operation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204858/discussion-between-blackxero-and-maddy23285).

Comment: Resolved the issue by removing content and datatype from request headers. Corssorigin was not an issue because I have lot of ajax requests in same project requesting same server and haven't faced this issue before. But this is the first time I am doing GET operation with query string parameters. I always used form values before.

Answer (score 0):

you can try passing custom headers

```
headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            "Accept": 'application/json',
        }
```

Comment: It worked by removing the content type and data type from request headers. Because I am working with query string parameters.