# CORS in NodeJS app that has type "module"

Tags: node.js, paypal, cors

I have two apps in VSCode, a Python Flask app that submits a POST request to PayPal NodeJS app.
Here is the [PayPal documentation on the NodeJS app](https://github.com/paypal-examples/docs-examples/tree/main/standard-integration).

When I go to http://127.0.0.1:5000 the Flask web app submits a POST request to the PayPal NodeJS app at http://127.0.0.1:8888. The web browser console captures the following.

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://api2.amplitude.com/2/httpapi with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.
POST http://127.0.0.1:8888/my-server/create-paypal-order net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

[This Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50873764/cross-origin-read-blocking-corb) has an answer that mentions adding CORS to NodeJS.

The PayPal NodeJS app is `"type": "module"` (not `"type": "commonjs"`). Most articles I'm finding on Google and Stack Overflow explain how to use CORS in a CommonJS NodeJS app. I installed CORS in VSCode using `npm install cors` and then added these lines to NodeJS server.js.

```
const cors = import("cors");
app.use(cors());
```

And I get the following.

```
TypeError: cors is not a function
```

I am not sure how to configure a NodeJS app that has `"type": "module"` so that POST requests are NOT blocked by CORS policy.

Comment: FWIW, a frontend in Flask and backend in NodeJS does not make much sense. The  example from PayPal is just in a widely understood language (Javascript), you should be able to easily implement the backend in Flask if that is what you want to contain the whole system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct import syntax for using the cors package in type module is import cors from 'cors';

Comment: cool, thanks Moshe. After changing `const cors = import("cors");` to `import cors from 'cors';` I am no longer getting exception `TypeError: cors is not a function`. Thanks much for this answer. I am new to NodeJS and just couldn't find this answer via a Google or Stack Overflow search.